# Fix position of element when scrolled to it

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to hack into the scroll deck example so that when the user scrolls to slide #what5, this slide's position becomes fix and sticks to the top (top:0px) until the user scrolls down to another certain y distance. ie pause the scroll.

You can see here what I'm doing, when it reaches #what5 however it's position becomes fixed but the top remains at 3984px instead of 0px.

http://machinas.com/wip/hugoboss/scrolldeck/decks/responsive/

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
                var st = $(this).scrollTop();

                if ((st >= 3984) && (st <= 5040 ) ){
                        $('#what5').css({'position':'fixed'})
                        $('#what5').css({ ' top ': 0 +"px!important"})
                } else {

                    $('#what5').css({'position':'absolute', ' top ': 3984})
                }

            });
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is bad. Try this:

```
           if ((st >= 3984) && (st <= 5040 ) ){
                    $('#what5').css({position:'fixed', top : 0});
            } else {

                $('#what5').css({position:'absolute', top : 3984})
            }
```